# Failed to use the command npm install canvas in pycharm。

Tags: javascript, python

I can't read the log file. Somebody help me.Is it the dependency that I  need to install canvas?
Or is it something else?
Error message：

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\PycharmProjects\js\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Warning: Missing input files:
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libfreetype-6.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libgthread-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\zlib1.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpango-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libgmodule-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libfontconfig-1.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libintl-8.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpng14-14.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libexpat-1.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libcairo-2.dll
npm ERR!  ڴ˽        һ      һ    Ŀ    Ҫ   ò      ɣ      ӡ -m     ء 
npm ERR!   Backend.cc
npm ERR! D:\PycharmProjects\js\node_modules\canvas\src\backend\Backend.h(3,10): fatal  error C1083:  ޷      ļ :   cairo.h  : No such file or directory [D:\PycharmProjects\js\node_modul 
es\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'D:\NodeJs\node.exe D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-g
yp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=D:\PycharmProjects\js\n
ode_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=D:\PycharmPro
jects\js\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v108-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install request to https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/relea
ses/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v108-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN github.com
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.2 and node@18.15.0 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error request to https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/rel
eases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v108-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN github.com
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.3 found at "D:\Pycharm_P\PyCharm 2023.1\jbr\bin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.4.33110.190) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn D:\Pycharm_P\PyCharm 2023.1\jbr\bin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\PycharmProjects\\js\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\97995\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.15.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\97995\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.15.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=D:\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\97995\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.15.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\PycharmProjects\\js\\node_modules\\canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\PycharmProjects\\js\\node_modules\\canvas\\build',       
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "D:\\NodeJs\\node.exe" "D:\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules
\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=D:\\P
ycharmProjects\\js\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release\\canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas"
 "--module_path=D:\\PycharmProjects\\js\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\PycharmProjects\js\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'D:\NodeJs\node.exe D:\NodeJs\node_
modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --update-binary -
-module=D:\PycharmProjects\js\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=can
vas --module_path=D:\PycharmProjects\js\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\PycharmProjects\js\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)     
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "D:\\NodeJs\\node.exe" "D:\\PycharmProjects\\js\\node_modu
les\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\PycharmProjects\js\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.10
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\97995\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-19T05_53_50_663Z-debug-0.log
```

I got an error when I ran the js code: Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package).
So I went to install canvas and got an error.
But I can't read the log information very well.